# Float in CSS3 troubleshooting

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create two columns of text inside a "content-wrapper" but as soon as I enter the second CSS rule to "float:left" at the #box2, both the columns seems to escape the content-wrapper.

```
@charset "UTF-8";


body

{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#ccc;



}

#content {
    background-color:#fff;
    max-width:960px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:#333;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#header
{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;    

}

#menu   {
    width:auto;
    margin-top:1%;

}


#menu a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#666;
    margin-right:3%;


}

#menu a:hover{
    color:#333;


}

#sidfot1{
    background-color:#999999;
    }

#sidfot2{
    background-color:#854242;
    }

    #overheader h4  {
        color:#854242;
        margin-left:42.5%;

        }

    #overheader h3  {
        color:#854242;
        margin-left:35%;
        padding-top:2%;

        }

#searchbar  {
    width:auto;
    float:right;
    margin:1%;
    }

hr  {
    border-color:#834342;
    }

#box1{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    margin:3%;

    }

#box2   {
    width:40%;
    float:left;
    margin:3%;

    }
```

And here's the html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='standard.css' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>


<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Responsiv Design</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
<section id="overheader">
<h3>Webbutveckling för mobila enheter</h3>
<h4>Responsiv Webbdesign</h4>
<section id="searchbar"> <input type="text"/> <input type="button" value="Sök"/> </section>
</section>
<header id="header">
<img src="header.jpg" alt="mittuniversitetet">
<section id="menu">
<a href="#">Startsida</a><a href="#">SIDA 2</a><a href="#">SIDA 3</a><a href="#">MIUN</a>
</section>
<hr>

<section id="box1"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi non ullamcorper augue. 
Donec malesuada consectetur urna et laoreet. Mauris aliquet neque a felis consequat sollicitudin. 
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; 
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; 
Donec justo ligula, sagittis ac orci id, tristique dignissim ligula. Donec hendrerit augue 
vitae massa consequat, nec malesuada metus mattis.</p></section>
<section id="box2">
<p>
Fusce tempus sodales lectus sit amet semper. Ut mollis justo eu nisl bibendum, 
luctus vestibulum nisi accumsan. Donec sed magna felis. Fusce interdum, ligula at 
scelerisque euismod, diam velit pharetra lectus, quis blandit mauris est id libero.
 Integer a viverra nunc, nec efficitur orci. Praesent pellentesque, metus sed tempor ultrices, 
 lorem lectus sagittis mi, ac ultrices mi neque at massa. Phasellus laoreet, nunc ac dapibus fringilla,
  justo metus hendrerit velit, sed euismod enim dui nec massa. Cras fringilla malesuada eros, a vehicula justo semper nec.</p>
</p></section>

</div><!--Div conent ends-->
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to find a solution to this problem, but I can not. I have added clear:both, checking names, rules, spelling, etc. I have reduced the size of the columns, float right.
But I just can't find what is causing this problem.

I think I got it all down.

/thanks

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with the problem?

Comment: you didn't close your `<header>`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this here: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zmtbra14/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3qcuv3bx/

Closed the header now. Thanks.
The problem is already explained at the top of post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floats are removed from the flow so the background-color of #content will not enclose your two floated columns unless you use a containing mechanism. If you don't need visible overflow then simply add **overflow:hidden** to #content otherwise if you do need visible overflow then use another containing technique such as 'clearfix' (google it) which is well documented around the web.

As mentioned above you haven't closed the header element either.

Answer (score 0):

Try it-
close your `header` tag

```css
body

{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#ccc;



}

#content {
    background-color:#fff;
    max-width:960px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:#333;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#header
{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;    

}

#menu   {
    width:auto;
    margin-top:1%;

}


#menu a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#666;
    margin-right:3%;


}

#menu a:hover{
    color:#333;


}

#sidfot1{
    background-color:#999999;
    }

#sidfot2{
    background-color:#854242;
    }

    #overheader h4  {
        color:#854242;
        margin-left:42.5%;

        }

    #overheader h3  {
        color:#854242;
        margin-left:35%;
        padding-top:2%;

        }

#searchbar  {
    width:auto;
    float:right;
    margin:1%;
    }

hr  {
    border-color:#834342;
    }

#box1{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    margin:3%;

    }

#box2   {
    width:40%;
    float:left;
    margin:3%;

    }
```

```html
<div id="content">
<section id="overheader">
<h3>Webbutveckling för mobila enheter</h3>
<h4>Responsiv Webbdesign</h4>
<section id="searchbar"> <input type="text"/> <input type="button" value="Sök"/> </section>
</section>
<header id="header">
<img src="header.jpg" alt="mittuniversitetet">
<section id="menu">
<a href="#">Startsida</a><a href="#">SIDA 2</a><a href="#">SIDA 3</a><a href="#">MIUN</a>
</section>
  </header>
<hr>

<section id="box1"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi non ullamcorper augue. 
Donec malesuada consectetur urna et laoreet. Mauris aliquet neque a felis consequat sollicitudin. 
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; 
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; 
Donec justo ligula, sagittis ac orci id, tristique dignissim ligula. Donec hendrerit augue 
vitae massa consequat, nec malesuada metus mattis.</p></section>
<section id="box2">
<p>
Fusce tempus sodales lectus sit amet semper. Ut mollis justo eu nisl bibendum, 
luctus vestibulum nisi accumsan. Donec sed magna felis. Fusce interdum, ligula at 
scelerisque euismod, diam velit pharetra lectus, quis blandit mauris est id libero.
 Integer a viverra nunc, nec efficitur orci. Praesent pellentesque, metus sed tempor ultrices, 
 lorem lectus sagittis mi, ac ultrices mi neque at massa. Phasellus laoreet, nunc ac dapibus fringilla,
  justo metus hendrerit velit, sed euismod enim dui nec massa. Cras fringilla malesuada eros, a vehicula justo semper nec.
</p></section>

</div><!--Div conent ends-->
```

Comment: I have already closed the header.
What I want to achiev is to keep the box1/2 inside the content wrapper. As you can see the content wrapper's background is white. And with the "float:left;" at #box2 messes up everything.

Answer (score 0):

There are tow ways to resolve this issue.
1) Add the "float:left or float:right" to the "content-wrapper".
2) Add a box after box to add give it style "clear:both". like